# PyQt5 - Button activated incorrectly from parent window

Tags: pyqt5

Using `PyQt5`, I am trying to create a `QApplication` with:

- a `QMainWindow` containing a `QPushButton` to create a second window (`QWidget`)
- a second window containing a "Browse" button (`QPushButton`) to open a file (`QFileDialog`)

As I plan to have several "Browse" buttons, each with a `QLabel` and a `QLineEdit` to display the selected file, I created a `class BrowseFile(QWidget)` which disposes these three elements into a `QHBoxLayout` (note that the MWE below contains only the "Browse" button).

For some reason, when clicking on the button from the main window to open the second window, the `QFileDialog` shows up. Could someone explain me how to link the action to my "Browse" button properly? I think have a problem in my class definitions.

**MWE**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QFileDialog, QPushButton

class BrowseFile(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BrowseFile,self).__init__()        
        
        self.layout=QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        self.browse_button=QPushButton("Browse", self)
        self.browse_button.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog())

        self.layout.addWidget(self.browse_button)
        
    def open_dialog(self):
        QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)

class SecondWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondWindow,self).__init__()
                
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        
        self.browse_file=BrowseFile()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.browse_file, 0,0,1,1)
                
        self.setLayout(self.layout)    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        
        self.button=QPushButton(self,text="Some button")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_click)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)
               
    def button_click(self):
        self.second_window=SecondWindow()
        self.second_window.show()

###############
app=QApplication([])

main_window=MainWindow()
main_window.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: This line is the problem: `self.browse_button.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog())`. You're not connecting a function. You're executing the function `self.open_dialog()`, and connecting its return value. In this case: None. In order to make it work, pass the reference of the function: `self.browse_button.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)`.

Comment: For the MWE, you are right, it solves the problem. However, in my complete code, I need to pass arguments to `self.open_dialog`. How can I do so?

Comment: You can use a lambda: `self.browse_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.open_dialog())`.

Comment: Works like a charm! If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it.